# Peer dependencies vs. (re-)exporting dependencies in abstract hierarchy (framework)

Tags: frameworks, dependencies, typescript, npm

Say I have a module `storage-abstract`, which contains abstract logic (framework) for storing key/values. I also have some (arbitrarily many) implementations of this abstraction, each in a separate module, like `storage-files`, `storage-db`, `storage-cloud` and so on.

Now say that there is a class `AbstractStorage` in `storage-abstract` that looks like follows:

```
// in storage-abstract
import {Interval} from 'some-3rd-party-lib';

abstract class AbstractStorage {
  // ...
  protected abstract _storageLimit: Interval;
}

export {AbstractStorage}
```

Now each concrete storage has to provide its own value for  `_storageLimit` and thus know `Interval`. I could solve this the following way:

```
// in storage-files
import {AbstractStorage} from 'storage-abstract';
import {Interval} from 'some-3rd-party-lib';

class FilesStorage extends AbstractStorage {
  // ...
  protected _storageLimit = new Interval(1, 7);
}

export {FilesStorage}
```

This works fine, but the problem is that now `storage-abstract` and `storage-files` may depend on different versions of `some-3rd-party-lib`, causing subtle bugs somewhere. The approach to prevent this (at least for NPM) is to specify `some-3rd-party-lib` as a peer dependency (with a certain version) of `storage-abstract` I assume.

But there is another approach: Given that `storage-abstract` is in some sense like an API to `storage-files`, it may (re-)export `Interval`; `storage-files` may then use this export and thus no longer depend on `some-3rd-party-lib` directly (or its own version of it):

```
// in storage-abstract
// ...
export {
  AbstractStorage,
  Interval, // <-- new
}
```

```
// in storage-files
import {
  AbstractStorage,
  Interval, // <-- new
} from 'storage-abstract';
// removed: import {Interval} from 'some-3rd-party-lib';
// ...
```

Which approach is the better (or what are advantages and disadvantages)?

Comment: Would you look on this question any different if `Interval` was used in a public method of `AbstractStorage` and not just in a private/protected part? Why/Why not?

Comment: No, I think I would not. With `Interval` being exposed by a public method, it became part of the interfaces of `AbstractStorage` as well as `FilesStorage`, but that does not seem to have an influence on the potential versioning problem between those classes.